How to check called function. Vitest
I'm using Vitest.
I have a main function checkForm, it can contain 2 or more functions with extensive logic. Therefore we can't extract logic from update and refresh
const update = (): void => {
    console.log('update');
};
const refresh = (): void => {
    console.log('refresh');
};
const checkForm = (): void => {
    update();
    refresh();
};

I have a test where I check if functions are called, inside the main function
describe('Test.vue', () => {
 let wrapper;
 let vm;

 beforeEach(() => {
     const pinia = createTestingPinia({
         createSpy: vi.fn,
     });
     wrapper = shallowMount(Test, {
         global: {
             plugins: [pinia],
         },
     });
     vm = wrapper.vm;
 });
 afterEach(() => {
     wrapper.unmount();
     vi.resetAllMocks();
 });
 it('checkForm', async () => {
     await vm.checkForm();

     expect(vm.update).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
});

But i get error [Function update] is not a spy or a call to a spy!
How to check that a function has been called?

You’ll have to inject that function and mock it

@Jessika You can't do this. Testing comps that use composition api presumes gray-box testing, you treat a component as a single unit. This doesn't differ from having const checkForm = (): void => { console.log('update'); console.log('refresh'), refresh/update are implementation details that need to be ignored. In this case you need to test the actual work that checkForm does, i.e assert that console.log is called

@EstusFlask This is an example, what if there are not two, but more functions. And when there is more code inside the functions

@Jessika Please, update the question so it would reflect your real case

@EstusFlask updated

@Jessika It still contains only console.log. But any way, there's isn't really any difference. In its current state you need to test checkForm as if "update" and "refresh" don't exist. As said above, implementation details need to be ignored, focus on asserting and spying what they do. If there are request, mock them. If update/refresh are complex enough on their own this means they need to be extracted to a separate module to improve testability, probably as a composable
